# AutoML (Azure ML Service): Getting probabilities from the deployed model

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Does the deployed autoML classification model can return probabilities as well? Right now it seems to return only class name.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AutoML models adhere to the scikit interfaces and are scikit pipelines. Therefore, you can use `predict_proba()` on the model to obtain probabilities.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @Mutatos In case you have have already ran an experiment. You can obtain the model by using `_, best_model = run.get_output()`. 

You can then infer i.e; obtain the probabilities by using `best_model.predict_proba(X)`